# Is there any way to use Jasmine default matchers within custom matchers?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, matcher

I have a custom matcher in some Jasmine test specs of the form:

```
this.addMatchers({
    checkContains: function(elem){
        var found = false;
        $.each( this.actual, function( actualItem ){

            // Check if these objects contain the same properties.
            found = found || actualItem.thing == elem;
        });
        return found;
    }
});
```

Of course, `actualItem.thing == elem` doesn't actually compare object contents- I have to use one of the more complex solutions in [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript).

I can't help but notice, though, that Jasmine already has a nice object equality checker: [expect(x).toEqual(y)](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/Matchers.js#L100).  Is there any way to use that within a custom matcher?  Is there any general way to use matchers within custom matchers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is slightly hacky but entirely possible.

The first thing we need to do is make the Jasmine.Env class available. Personally I have done this in my SpecRunner.html since its already setup there anyway. On the load of my SpecRunner I have the following script that runs:

```
(function() {
      var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
      jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

      var trivialReporter = new jasmine.TrivialReporter();

      jasmineEnv.addReporter(trivialReporter);

      jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
        return trivialReporter.specFilter(spec);
      };

      var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;

      window.onload = function() {
        if (currentWindowOnload) {
          currentWindowOnload();
        }
        execJasmine();
      };

      function execJasmine() {
        jasmineEnv.execute();
      };

    })();
```

So after the *execJasmine* function declaration I push the jasmineEnv into the global namespace by adding this:

```
this.jasmineEnv = jasmineEnv;
```

Now, in any of my spec files I can access the jasmineEnv variable and that is what contains the matchers core code.

Looking at toEqual specifically, toEqual calls the *jasmine.Env.prototype.equals_* function. This means that in your customMatcher you can do the following:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    this.addMatchers({
        isJasmineAwesome    : function(expected){
            return jasmineEnv.equals_(this.actual, expected);
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, using this method will only give you access to the following methods:

1. compareObjects_
2. equals_
3. contains_

The rest of the matchers reside the jasmine.Matchers class but I have not been able to make that public yet. I hope this helps you out in someway or another

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  This may well be a case where the solution I was looking for (the one you gave) is worse than the problem I was trying to a avoid (my own object equality checker).  Very cool, nonetheless, though.

Comment: If you're wanting to use a custom matcher A within another custom matcher B, you can add the logic for your matcher A to the jasmine.Env.prototype and then call that log from within your matcher B by using jasmine.getEnv().myMatcherFn().